# Easy way to check installed software and configurations?

Tags: server, software-installation

I am wondering if there is an easy way to make sure to get a list of all installed software on an Ubuntu server (both from source and from apt-get).
This should hopefully include important data directories and cronjobs.
The reason for this is that there needs to be an extra server holding the exact same software as the current machine (same cronjobs, website files, software, databases etc) but there is no documentation or list of what is installed and what is not.
(This is a live-production server with always users being online, making a clone is not a feasible option due to the shear size (We are talking 1TB+ of data) and we need to get it documented somehow anyway what is installed and what is important)

Comment: My specific issue is that there are a lot of custom scripts and programs on it, some of which are not a package but manually compiled from source and put to run in /etc/init.d.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command to find the installed software or packages:

```
$dpkg --get-selections
```

If you want to specific installed package or software then you can use following command:

```
$dpkg --get-selections | grep <package/software name>
```